# Utiliza-se hífen, meia-risca ou travessão para separar nome de artista de nome de álbum ou música?

Tags: pontuação

Existe algum padrão para separar nomes de artistas de nomes de seus álbuns ou músicas? Esta estrutura é encontrada em listagens de obras, por exemplo, ou em sistemas de arquivamento (como arquivos digitais em computadores). Ou seja, há uma forma correta ou preferível dentre as seguintes?

Chico Buarque - Construção (1971)

Chico Buarque – Construção (1971)

Chico Buarque — Construção (1971)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não há uma recomendação específica para qual sinal deve ser utilizado. No entanto, posso assegurar que não é o travessão, observe:

O travessão não há como ser porque ele só é utilizado nas seguintes situações:

1. Introduzir uma pergunta ou resposta;
2. Separar frases com sentido de aposto, exemplo: O carro — que tinha sido o responsável pelo acidente — acabou por explodir.

O hífen também não é a melhor opção. Isso porque ele só é utilizado nas seguintes situações:

1. Separação silábica;
2. Separação de palavras compostas;
3. Conjugações verbais (como olho-me e vejo-me).

Então, acredito que o melhor seja utilizar a meia-risca, que é um tanto mais genérica.

Todas as minhas afirmações estão presentes nestes manuais de comunicação da Secretaria de Comunicação brasileira: https://abre.ai/hifen e https://abre.ai/travessaopt. Quanto à meia-risca, não encontrei nada concreto o suficiente, mas tomei como base minha experiência de vida, diversos sites na internet e exemplos de títulos de músicas que utilizam a meia-risca para separar o autor do título.

Comment: Concordo completamente com suas considerações. Você tem alguma fonte que as corrobore? Um manual de estilo, um tratado tipográfico...?

Comment: Sim. Todas as minhas afirmações estão presentes nestes manuais de comunicação da Secretaria de Comunicação brasileira: http://abre.ai/hifen e http://abre.ai/travessaopt. Quanto à meia-risca, não encontrei nada concreto o suficiente, mas tomei como base minha experiência de vida, diversos sites na internet e exemplos de títulos de músicas que utilizam a meia-risca para separar o autor do título..

Comment: Bem-vindo Chanp! Boas referências estas que citaste no comentário! Podes editar tua resposta e adicioná-las? Assim tua resposta gaha mais embasamento!

Comment: Feito. Muito obrigado!